# Why is this onClick event not being applied correctly?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm using late-binding to assign `onClick` events to checkboxes (styled as dots). My first assignment [located at https://github.com/farfromunique/vampirrePoints/blob/master/events.js#L264 ] goes perfectly, and reacts as expected - all dots have this as their onClick:

```
/* https://github.com/farfromunique/vampirrePoints/blob/master/main.js#L440 */
allDots[i].onclick = function() { 
    if (this.checked) {
        decrementCounter(1);
    } else {
        incrementCounter(1);
    };
}
```

However, when `Step11()` is triggered, and `freebieDotSetup()` is called, only *some* of the checkboxes get their `onClick`s updated. Specifically, `sta1, sta2, sta3, sta4, sta5` (possibly others, too) keep their initial value.

I have tried putting `console.log()` statements in during the assignment process, and it looks like the assignment happens, but it doesn't "stick". Why doesn't this work?

Code reference (whole site): https://github.com/farfromunique/vampirrePoints

By request, a non-working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/farfromunique/mS4Lp/

Note: the menu is on the wrong side, doesn't advance properly, and none of the "dots" (checkboxes) are clickable, so functionality is not testable. I strongly suspect that my code is not cross-browser compatible, but that isn't a priority for me (yet).

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle with your problem.

Comment: @APaul I'm having a hard time not being incredibly frustrated by this request. if my JS, CSS and HTML were 100% complete, universally compatible, and working, this wouldn't be a big ask... but I wouldn't need help. My JSFiddle-ifiedpage doesn't work at all, and I don't even know where to begin to try to get it to work. I supposed that makes me unworthy of your attention.

Comment: Provide a non working fiddle, I did not asked for a working fiddle. Crete a fiddle share it and state the problem. If we do jot understand your issue how we will help you?

Comment: @APaul JSFiddle link added. See note above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution: In the function `freebieDotSetup()`, I was doing this:

```
for (i=0;i<attributeDots.length;i++) {
    attributeDots[i] = allDots[i];
}
...
for (i=0;i<abilityDots.length;i++) {
    abilityDots[i] = allDots[i+attributeDots.length];
}
...
for (i=0;i<disciplineDots.length;i++) {
    disciplineDots[i] = allDots[i+abilityDots.length];
}
...
```

Since I was using the previous group's length, it would occasionally overwrite the previous values (due to groups being shorter). I corrected this with this:

```
startPos = startPos + attributeDots.length;

for (i=0;i<abilityDots.length;i++) {
    abilityDots[i] = allDots[i+startPos];
}
```

Adding the previous group's length to startPos each time. Making this change resolved my issue.

... But the JSFiddle is totally busted, still.